Bootstrap 4 scrolling table with fixed header
I have 2 tables on a page. The first one should not scroll and the other should scroll with a fixed header. My issue is when I use the CSS styling on that page, it makes the widths and heights out of sync and messes up the styling within Bootstrap 4 for the first table.  How can I avoid this issue? Is there a Bootstrap 4 automatic style to consider when doing this?


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered pull-left dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <small class="w-100">
                    <p class="text-danger">
                        <b>
                            (" * ")
                        </b>
                        Indicates Required Field
                    </p>
                </small>
            </div>
            <th style="width:8%">
                <label class="required">
                    <b>
                        Ris Order
                    </b>
                </label>
            </th>
            <th style="width:4%">
                <label class="required">
                    <b>
                        Station
                    </b>
                </label>
            </th>
            <th style="width:6%">
                <label class="required">
                    <b>
                        Weapon Pos.
                    </b>
                </label>
            </th>
            <th style="width:8%">
                <label class="required">
                    <b>
                        Store
                    </b>
                </label>
            </th>
            <th style="width:4%">
                Weapon Code
            </th>
            <th style="width:4%">
                Code Display
            </th>
            <th style="width:4%">
                Ris Mode
            </th>
            <th style="width:8%">
                Program
            </th>
            <th style="width:8%">
                Interval 1
            </th>
            <th style="width:6%">
                Units 
            </th>
            <th style="width:10%">
                Fuzing
            </th>
            <th style="width:4%">
                Drag
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="gradeX warning">
            <td>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" name=""
                           value="" pattern="" placeholder="" required="True">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <select id="DateOfBirthMonth" name="" class="form-control" required="True">
                        <option value="">
                            ----
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">
                            January
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            February
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            March
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            April
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            May
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">
                            June
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <select id="DateOfBirthMonth" name="" class="form-control" required="True">
                        <option value="">
                            ----
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">
                            January
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            February
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            March
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            April
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            May
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">
                            June
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <select id="DateOfBirthMonth" name="" class="form-control" required="True">
                        <option value="">
                            ----
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">
                            January
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            February
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            March
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            April
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            May
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">
                            June
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <select id="DateOfBirthMonth" name="" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">
                            ----
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">
                            January
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            February
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            March
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            April
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            May
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">
                            June
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <select id="DateOfBirthMonth" name="" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">
                            ----
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">
                            January
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            February
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            March
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            April
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            May
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">
                            June
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <select id="DateOfBirthMonth" name="" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">
                            ----
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">
                            January
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            February
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            March
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            April
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            May
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">
                            June
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <select id="DateOfBirthMonth" name="" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">
                            ----
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">
                            January
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            February
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            March
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            April
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            May
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">
                            June
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" name=""
                           value="" pattern="" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <select id="DateOfBirthMonth" name="" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">
                            ----
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">
                            January
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            February
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            March
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            April
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            May
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">
                            June
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <select id="DateOfBirthMonth" name="" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">
                            ----
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">
                            January
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            February
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            March
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            April
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            May
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">
                            June
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <select id="DateOfBirthMonth" name="" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">
                            ----
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">
                            January
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            February
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            March
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            April
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">
                            May
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">
                            June
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="row gutter">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="widget">
            <div class="widget-header">
                <div class="title">
                    Pass Record
                </div>
                <span class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs">
                    </i>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin table-fixed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:10%">
                                    No.
                                </th>
                                <th style="width:15%">
                                    Date
                                </th>
                                <th style="width:30%" class="hidden-phone">
                                    Description
                                </th>
                                <th style="width:10%" class="hidden-phone">
                                    Qnty
                                </th>
                                <th style="width:10%" class="hidden-phone">
                                    VAT
                                </th>
                                <th style="width:10%" class="hidden-phone">
                                    Total
                                </th>
                                <th style="width:15%" class="hidden-phone">
                                    Actions
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    ##310934
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    14-02-1214
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    Drive synergies rich viral...
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    4
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    <span class="label label-info">
                                        2.24%
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    50.00$
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    <a href="##" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">
                                        View
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="##" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
                                        Edit
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    ##265049
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    13-02-1214
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    Incentivize user-contributed...
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    21
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    <span class="label label-info">
                                        6.59%
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    130.00$
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    <a href="##" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">
                                        View
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="##" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
                                        Edit
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    ##443567
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    11-02-1214
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    Enable innovate tagclouds...
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    9
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    <span class="label label-info">
                                        2.50%
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    220.00$
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    <a href="##" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">
                                        View
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="##" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
                                        Edit
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    ##480998
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    18-02-1214
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    Tagclouds dynamic, intuitive...
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    7
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    <span class="label label-info">
                                        3.124%
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    530.00$
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    <a href="##" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">
                                        View
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="##" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
                                        Edit
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    ##550347
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    13-02-1214
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    Front-end web services...
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    27
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    <span class="label label-info">
                                        4.57%
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    350.00$
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-phone">
                                    <a href="##" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">
                                        View
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="##" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
                                        Edit
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




Can you provide a working snippet of the issue? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1533592
